# Como usar variável global Javascript com vue js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Sei que a questão é bem primária, mas também é meu estagio em desenvolvimento web, me perdoem

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
const user = ref(null);

export default function useAuthUser() {
  const { supabase } = useSupabase();

  const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email,
      password,
    });
    if (error) throw error;
    return user;
  };
}
```

Em uma outra página vue consigo fazer o seguinte:

```
<div>{{user.id}}</div>
```

Ele renderiza sem problemas.
Mas não consigo por exemplo:

```js
onMounted(() => {
      alert(user.id)
    });
```

Ele retorna undefined